# iPhone sockets - 3g vs. wifi

Tags: iphone, sockets, wifi

I have developed a trivial example application leveraging the example CFNetwork code listed here,

http://dev.im.ethz.ch/wiki/Socket_communication_on_the_iPhone

and combined it with the SpeakHere example on the apple developer site.  Using this I have managed a very, very crude mechanism to stream audio to my server.  It works surprisingly well over wifi, but hangs/bombs out over the 3g network.  I had hoped that 3g/wifi would be transparent with respect to this issue but that doesn't seem to be the case.  Is there any documentation regarding salient differences between these two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3G very likely has much longer latency and much more latency *variation* than wifi.  So you should be looking into auto-tuning your jitter buffer to handle latency spikes.

Comment: is this in reference to Asterisk/Freeswitch, or a more general issue which I could deal with in my iPhone code? I'm not actually doing VoIP so if it's the former I'm not sure how I'd go about that.

Comment: This is a general issue with streaming over wireless networks; they're not as consistent as wired networks, and as it happens cellular is less consistent than wifi.

Comment: thanks again for the feedback.  i wonder if just using the asyncsocket library would be sufficient to abstract this away so that i dont have to think about it. that seems to be the most widely recommended approach.  i also noticed that by turning down the number of expected bytes to read on the server side, the situation significantly improves. am i correct in assuming that this is what you are referring to?  sorry if these are still silly questions, im not yet 100% sure what side to focus my efforts on.